# No resource type specified (at 'id' with value '@+id\st')

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I'm new at android programming, I'm now trying to make some *buttons*, I configured these buttons using the following code:

The **MainActivity** class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button st,nd,center;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        st = (Button)findViewById(R.id.st);
        st = (Button)findViewById(R.id.center);
        st = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nd);


    }
}
```

and the **XML Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello from animation!!"
    />
<button android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="1st half"
android:id="@+id\st"
/>
// and the other two points defined the same way
</LinearLayout>
```

And i got that syntax error:

```
error: Error: No resource type specified (at 'id' with value '@+id\st').
// and the same error with the other two buttons
```

**HINT:** The `R class` is imported and accessible from the `MainActivity` class but it can't read `R.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `button` with `Button`  and `android:id="@+id\st"` with `android:id="@+id/st"`

Answer (score 2):

there are some syntax errors in your code

first use `Button` instead of button.

use /  instead of \ after id.

```
<Button android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:text="1st half"
android:id="@+id/st"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `button` instead `Button`. It is case sensitive.
And at `android:id` replace the `\` through `/`

This is the correct code:

```
<Button android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="1st half"
    android:id="@+id/st"
/>
```

Replace your button code with this and it should work